# Develop Site Map for a Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap

I am developing a web site using ASP.Net and c#. I need to design a site map for the web site.
So can anyone suggest how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

In what sense? SEO sense? How to develop sense? Are you using any kind of CMS?

Is your website static?

Think about using bread crumbs as well (if you want this for SEO).

Comment: Better would be to add questions as comments. It would help others as well as the OP to classify the question.